# create array using two foreach

Tags: php, json

I hope you guys can help me here, because I guess my code is not made correctly.

I have 2 mysql tables:

```
table: checks
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id        | name        | host       |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 1         | demo 1      | 1.1.1.1    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 2         | demo 2      | 1.1.1.2    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 3         | demo 3      | 1.1.1.3    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+

table: checks_history
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id        | check_id    | status     | timestamp  |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | 1           | 0          | 3451245    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 2         | 1           | 0          | 3451245    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 3         | 2           | 0          | 3451245    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 4         | 1           | 1          | 3451245    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 5         | 2           | 0          | 3451245    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

I want create a json file per id (table: checks) with this structure:

```
{
    "info": { // Associated to table "checks"
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Demo 1",
        "host": "1.1.1.1"
    },
    "data": { // associated to table check_history according with the id on table check
        "1": { // associated to Column "id" on table checks_history
           "status": "0",
           "timestamp": "3451245"
        },
        "2": { 
           "status": "0",
           "timestamp": "3451245"
        },
        "4": { 
           "status": "1",
           "timestamp": "3451245"
        }
    }
}
```

There is my code PHP:

```
$info = array();
$history = array();

$incidents = $database->select("app_checks","*", false);

foreach ($incidents as $key => $value) {

    $id = $value['id']; 
    $name = $value['name']; 
    $host = $value['host']; 

    $check_history = $database->select("app_checks_history", "*", [ "checkid" => $id, "ORDER" => ['id' => 'DESC'], "LIMIT" => 30 ]);


    foreach ($check_history as $k => $v) {

            $history = array(
                $v['id'] => array(
                    'timestamp' => $v['timestamp'],
                    'status' => $v['status']
                )
            );
 
    }

    $info = array(
        'info'=> array(
            'id'=> $id, 
            'name'=> $name, 
            'host'=> $host
            ),
        'data' => $history
    );

    $json_data = json_encode($info, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $fileName = 'json/server_'.$id.'.json';
    file_put_contents($fileName, $json_data);
}
```

When I try run the code, im getting the first value on "data" instead all loop:

```
{
    "info": { 
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Demo 1",
        "host": "1.1.1.1"
    },
    "data": { 
        "1": { 
           "status": "0",
           "timestamp": "3451245"
        }
    }
}
```

I searched in the forum and I did not found any similar issue related to my code.
I appreciate any help here.

Thanks in advance.
br

Comment: One of the queries must be invalid and returning false instead of an array

Comment: @peprumo I updated the code. Please see the last part. Now I only get a single value on "data" instead all loop.. can you help me here?

Comment: `$history = array(....` is wrong as it will **replace** all items in $history array on every iteration of that loop so in json you get whatever the last assignment happens to be, what you need is `$history[] = array(....` so it will just append

Comment: @Viney I changed the $history = array( to $history[] = array( but now is printing the same values in all json files..
for example, server_1,json print correctly, but server_2,json print the values of server_1 + server_2.
server_3.json print the values of server_1 + server_2 + server_3... etc etc etc very confuse :S

Comment: well, i fixed with a function. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know PHP; however, I believe if you get your data model right, it should get you there. I would have my data model something like below in C#, an instance of `Check` class represent a check as per your table, serialize and save each instance in its own JSON file.

```cs
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Check
    {
        [JsonProperty("info")]
        public Info Info { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Dictionary<string, History> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class History
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Info
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("host")]
        public string Host { get; set; }
    }
}
```